# What do we call an algorithm that finds approximate solution sometimes and fails some other times?

Tags: algorithms, reference-request

Suppose you have a minimization problem $\Pi$. You know that finding a feasible solution to $\Pi$ is NP-hard. You have designed an algorithm $\mathfrak{A}$ to solve $\Pi$ and you prove the following:

- If $\mathfrak{A}$ finds a feasible solution to $\Pi$, then its value is upper bounded by $\rho\mathit{OPT}$ for some $\rho >1$ where $\mathit{OPT}$ denotes the optimal value of $\Pi$.
- If $\mathfrak{A}$ fails to find a feasible solution to $\Pi$, then it could return $0$ or in general something less than $\mathit{OPT}$. (Of course it violates some constraints of $\Pi$.)

What do we call such an algorithm in the literature?

I know that this is not an approximation algorithm by definition. Also, bi-criteria approximation algorithm would not produce a solution that is better than $\mathit{OPT}$. Is there a name for this algorithm?

Comment: Is it a randomized algorithm? maybe Monte-Carlo approximation algorithm?

Comment: Suppose it is a deterministic algorithm.

Comment: I don't know a term for this, but it is a $\rho$-approximation algorithm for a restricted class of instances.  It might be worth looking for a more natural description of that class (more natural than "the set of instances for which this algorithm finds a feasible solution"...).